Ошибка шифрования в Laravel 10
Начал делать логику шифрования/дешифрования, нашел такой пример:
$newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter($key, config('app.cipher'));
$encrypted = $newEncrypter->encrypt($plainTextToEncrypt);
$decrypted = $newEncrypter->decrypt($encrypted);

Завел тинкер и получаю следующую ошибку, куда копать?
Psy Shell v0.12.0 (PHP 8.2.8 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> config('app.key')
= "base64:TmT9pX6lRfDcWrFWlyLSYSOnyRShEiEFCv1MOD5aT+A="

> config('app.cipher')
= "AES-256-CBC"

> $newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter(config('app.key'), config('app.cipher'));

   RuntimeException  Unsupported cipher or incorrect key length. Supported ciphers are: aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc, aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm.

Чуть больше о приложении:
  Environment ......................................................................................................................................  
  Application Name ................................................................................................. ****** ******* ******** (local)
  Laravel Version .......................................................................................................................... 10.43.0
  PHP Version ................................................................................................................................ 8.2.8
  Composer Version ........................................................................................................................... 2.6.6
  Environment ................................................................................................................................ local
  Debug Mode ............................................................................................................................... ENABLED
  URL ............................................................................................................................... 127.0.0.1:8000
  Maintenance Mode ............................................................................................................................. OFF

  Cache ............................................................................................................................................
  Config .................................................................................................................................... CACHED
  Events ................................................................................................................................ NOT CACHED
  Routes ................................................................................................................................ NOT CACHED  
  Views ..................................................................................................................................... CACHED

  Drivers ..........................................................................................................................................
  Broadcasting .............................................................................................................................. pusher
  Cache ...................................................................................................................................... redis
  Database ................................................................................................................................... mysql
  Logs .............................................................................................................................. stack / single
  Mail ........................................................................................................................................ smtp
  Queue ....................................................................................................................................... sync
  Session .................................................................................................................................... redis


Проблему удалось решить следующим способом.
В классе Encrypter есть следующие определения:
private static $supportedCiphers = [
    'aes-128-cbc' => ['size' => 16, 'aead' => false],
    'aes-256-cbc' => ['size' => 32, 'aead' => false],
    'aes-128-gcm' => ['size' => 16, 'aead' => true],
    'aes-256-gcm' => ['size' => 32, 'aead' => true],
];

Так как я использую aes-256-cbc, ключ должен иметь длину 32, а мой текущий ключ имеет длину 51. Решение-костыль:
$newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter(substr(config('app.key'), 0, 32), config('app.cipher'));

Если кто-то знает более правильное решение, прошу об этом сообщить, буду признателен.
